# What are the minimum hardware requirements to run elementary OS?

Tags: system-installation, hardware

I have a 2007 core-duo laptop and wanted to know the system requirements for this OS. What are the minimum requirements.

Comment: One of my laptops has following specs: Core2Duo T7300 (2x2.0GHz)
4GB RAM (2x2GB DDR2)
Intel integrated graphics Mobile GM965
HDD 250GB Intel WLAN and Realtek ethernet Everything works out of the box and quite fast.
Try it!

Comment: That'll eat most Linux distros for breakfast...

Comment: Note that "Core Duo" is a 32-bit CPU, while "Core 2 Duo" is 64-bit. The 32-bit version of the OS will run on both. Otherwise, I'd recommend the 64-bit OS if you can run it.

Comment: What about ATOM CPU's in NETBOOKS, do they at least CRAWL with elementary OS loki too ?

Comment: Can elementary OS run on 1GiB or less CPU/RAM?

Answer (score 10):

### Recommended System Specifications

- Recent Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
- 4 GB of system memory (RAM)
- Solid state drive (SSD) with 15 GB of free space
- Internet access
- 1024×768 display

Learn more at
http://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#recommended-system-specifications

Comment: eOS 32bit on a P4 2.6 and Athlon XP 2000+ nVidia mx440 and 1GB DDR 400 requires patience. Desktop taking 15-20% CPU reources idle so bottleneck's on the CPU side. @fleamour's right about any Core2Duo but I'll check a CoreDUO Solo first before going on.

Comment: These are the recommended specs, not the minimum. eOS runs smoothly on a core2 duo, for example.