# Should I use the 32-bit or 64-bit system on a low-end laptop?

Tags: system-installation, cpu

I was thinking of installing Freya on an old laptop I used to work on. The laptop is a Compaq CQ58 and it has 4GB of RAM, an AMD E1-1200 1.4 GHz dual core processor, and AMD Radeon HD 7310 graphics. I was wondering if I should choose the 32-bit or the 64-bit version of elementary, because a friend installed the 64 bit version on the same laptop and he said the experience was fine overall but sluggish at times .

Comment: A rule of thumb is, if you have 4 gigs of RAM or more, install 64bit

Comment: 64-bit, there shouldn't be any problems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the minimum hardware requirements to run elementary OS?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/what-are-the-minimum-hardware-requirements-to-run-elementary-os)

Comment: I installed elementary OS 64-bit on my Sony VAIO VGN-NR120E with 2GB of RAM and it works perfectly

Comment: @PavelJanicek That doesn't actually answer the question though.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended that at 4GB of RAM and above, users use the 64-bit version, assuming they have a 64-bit capable CPU. You may, however, see a slight performance improvement by using the 32-bit version with PAE (included by default), as it uses slightly less memory.