# Revert back to Freya

Tags: release-freya

Total newby and definitely not a pc expert with a dreadfully slow Lenovo looked for a way to still use an ageing laptop. Found Elementary, struggled through the setup procedure as it was all new to me, and then tried Freya on my Lenovo 3000 n200 on usb disk. It seemed to work fine, the laptop was responsive enough, hurray! So I made the switch to Elementary instead of Windows Vista. Again struggled through the procedures and managed to destroy the pre-installed Windows in the process... told you I'm not an expert. In the end I found instructions somewhere on the net to format the internal disk in partitions or something and did a clean install. Since Freya had been replaced with Loki, it installed Loki for me. Although everything seems to work... it is sloooow. Been looking for solutions and think it's just too old and too little ram to run Loki. So would like to reinstall Frey (yes I formatted the USB which had Freya on it as well...) but can't find it anywhere on the Elementary website. I even read that Elementary is no longer supporting older systems? If that's true then they're as bad as Apple... I found some Torrents, whatever they are, but read warnings about malicious things in there? Some come with MD5 codes (no idea what they are or what to do with them). Would like to try Freya 32 bit, as I had on the USB stick. How do I go about it and... may I suggest to the Elementary team that making an easy to use 'installer' for the people who aren't computer wizz kids might be an Elementary requirement for the next Elementary update?

Comment: You should read: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8266/how-do-the-system-requirements-compare-between-elementary-os-releases and also to see the minimum hardware requirements http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/what-are-the-minimum-hardware-requirements-to-run-elementary-os

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are right, they do not permit to download the old version from the official site.
Anyway, here is the sourceForge [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/elementaryos/).